# How to use the new Basic Activity in Android Studio 4.2?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-activity

I use android studio 4.2. In this version, when I created a basic activity, it generated 2 new activities along with `MainActivity` and 'content_main'.
In addition to these, it also created `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment`.
In whatever articles I've read and videos watched, these two activities aren't supposed to be there...
Does anyone know how I am supposed to use these?

This is how it looks when I run the app-

[image: when the app starts]

And this is where it takes me when I press `next`-

[image: This]

According to the docs and youtube videos, it isn't supposed to be like this...
Somebody please tell me where to refer to learn this.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 are 2 new fragments, if you want to show 2 different screens in one activity then you should go for fragment. These fragments will help you to show 2 different screens in a single activity.

Comment: And what if i want it the way it used to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a Empty Activity and build your own design as you wish it will be better always.